# InAppBrowser not working in windows phone 8 using phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone-8

Recently i came across a problem for `Facebook login` from my app through the `InAppBrowser` for phonegap. I tried with ios and android source from Phonegap that worked good. When i tried the same for windows phone 8 its not working.

When i search with phonegap documentation from here [InAppBrowser - PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) it is provided only for ios and android.

Could anyone suggest me an idea InAppBrowser for phonegap in windows phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 was in very early stages at that time, and as a result, InAppBrowser was not supported.

You can do one of two things:

1) Look at `InAppBrowser`'s source code at: . Here you should be able to look at `plugin.xml` to work out the structure of the package, and install it into your project (it *might* be using deprecated classes - I could not tell you off the top of my head).

2) Look at the deprecated phonegap plugins folder here: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone/ChildBrowser. This is where plugins used to be installed before Cordova took them under their wing. ChildBrowser became InAppBrowser once Apache Cordova took the project on and called it InAppBrowser. So ChildBrowser would have been its original form.

Either way, you should be able to get one of two up and running (the first is probably the better of the two as it will have more up-to-date source code).